# Read file from deployed server on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a server deployed on Heroku through Heroku auto deployment method from GitHub. On that server I have a file named `subscription.json` which contains user data whenever user is registered. I want to see that file.

How can I access that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that file is in your repository you should be able to read it like any regular file.

However, this isn't going to work on Heroku:

> which contains user data whenever user is registered

Heroku's filesystem [is dyno-local and ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you make to it will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This happens frequently ([at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)).

For saving things like user uploads, Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) using a third-party service like Amazon S3. But in this case I think a database would be a much more appropriate solution.

Heroku has its own [PostgreSQL service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) that is very well supported and available out of the box. If you prefer to use another database there are [plenty of options](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. i don't need that info to be in db because it contains chrome fcm subscription object which is removed whenever user is logged out

Comment: @A.SamadSalaat, why does that make any difference? Don't you have the same issue if you save this data in a file?